# HTML button onload submit

Tags: javascript, button

I have a button example below

```
<button id="startrunning">go</button>
```

There is no form or anything I'm using on the same page java script to detect it's click. It will work like I want it to when I click it. I want to see when the page is loaded it will automatically submit it's self is there a way?

Thank you

Comment: You need a form to be able to submit.

Comment: I changed it to button only now. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QEu84/10/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit()
    {
        document.getElementById("startrunning").click(); // Simulates button click
        document.submitForm.submit(); // Submits the form without the button
    }
</script>

<body onload="submit()">
    <form id="submitForm">
        <button id="startrunning">go</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can automatically click it when the page loads, using the code below, but you need a form to submit something (you submit a form, not a button)

```
<body onLoad="document.getElementById('startrunning').click();">
```